# My windows tablet pc doesn't recognize hardware components

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, tablet

I have a tablet pc running windows 10.
When there was a windows update, windows broke and i reinstalled it. But now the computer doesn't recognize important components like battery, touch screen and loud speaker anymore.
The device is a chiligreen E-Board MW060. 
I already tried to install the drivers on chiligreen's official website, but it didn't work. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you need to install drivers again?

Comment: I already installed the drivers on chiligreen's official website but it didn't work, can you recommend some universal drivers?